# how to get class name from String

Tags: java

I am using spring batch in that I am passing class name as parameter to reader in that I want set that as my target class name.is there a way that we can get class name from a String.I tried with using reflection in that I am getting that class successfully.but I not able to set as my target type class
below is my code.

```
@Bean(name = "jMongoReader")
@StepScope
public MongoItemReader<Object> jsonDataReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[name]}") String className) {

    try {

        Class cls= Class.forName(className);
        reader.setTemplate(mongoConfig.getMongoTemplate());
        reader.setCollection("employeeInfo");
        reader.setTargetType((Class<? extends className>) className.class);
        reader.setQuery("{}");
        Map<String, Direction> sorts = new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>(1);
        sorts.put("_id", Sort.Direction.ASC);
        reader.setSort(sorts);
        reader.setFields(keys);
}
```

Comment: `className.class` is always `String` in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake on this line :

```
reader.setTargetType((Class<? extends className>) className.class);
```

It should be :

```
reader.setTargetType(cls);
```

Comment: By the way, you cannot do `Class<? extends className>` with `className` a variable. You can do it only if it was a type.